# Many Single Sites, One Plugin directory - adjust plugins_url()

Tags: plugin-development, constants

*[this is not a Multisite question]*

> Update: this question is a logical impossibility, or a mind loop if you will, check update bellow.

The technique is [laid out here in WPEngineer](http://wpengineer.com/2374/easier-plugin-development-by-moving-plugin-directory/).
It allows having a single plugins folder to serve many WordPress sites running in the same server.

So, all my development sites have this in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/www_dev/base-site/wp-content/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://base-site.dev/wp-content/plugins');
```

Only the base-site has a plugins folder and don't have this constants set in its wp-config.

I found a situation where I am in *other-site.dev* and the plugin tries to call *base-site.dev*, as follows:

- the plugin in question is Advanced Custom Fields, but I guess it can happen in any other
- the Export XML function of the plugin calls this address `http://base-site.dev/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/actions/export.php`
- in theory, it should be `http://other-site.dev/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/actions/export.php`, but this address doesn't exist

The plugin builds the form action that executes the export function using this variable `$this->dir = plugins_url('',__FILE__);`

**The question is**: could we make an htaccess rule or apply a filter to overcome this issue?

## [update]

After anmari input and taking a closer look, I think there's no solution for this.
The [plugins_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) **uses** `WP_PLUGIN_URL`.

The plugin is rendering the following html:
`<form action="http://base-site.dev/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/actions/export.php" method="post">`

and there is no, and never will be, anything like:
`<form action="http://other-site.dev/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/actions/export.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are saying is that it then 'exports' the wrong system's xml (I'm not familiar with the plugin) ?

Ideally the plugin itself should be including/using the code rather in such a way so that it still knows the context/system in which it is being used irrespective of where the code is stored.

Have you tried seeing if the plugin author can update the plugin code rather ? Or perhaps getting someone to look at the code and offer a fix for it.

That would be a better solution rather than messing with htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly input, anmari. I've updated my question, but I think the essence is: *no, this will never work*. Cheers and thanks again for dropping by :)